# Two hardly equal excel tables loaded using OLEDB - got one header and one without

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, office-interop

I'm loading two Excel Worksheets. Both have exactly the same header in Row 1.
I' using the same code for both.

Now, I got a header for the second file, and no header for the first one.

Code:

```
    private static string GetExcelConnectionString(string Filename){return "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + Filename + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";}

    private static void AddToListByOLE(string Filename, ref System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataTable> MyList, int nTab = -1)
    {
        string sql = string.Empty;
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(GetExcelConnectionString(Filename)))
        {
            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter())
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    System.Data.DataTable dtSchema = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

                    string firstSheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME");

                    sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + firstSheetName + "]";
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    adapter.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        dt.Load(reader);
                    }
                    cn.Close();

                    MyList.Add(dt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Imput - both excel workbooks displayed overlapped:
[image: Both excel workbooks - overlapped displayed]

Connection string:
[image: Used connection string]

Result of first import (no header in DataTable):
[image: First worksheet imported - no header]

Result of second import (correct import with header):
[image: Second worksheet imported - with header]

Does anybody has an idea? I'm really out of ideas, as I'm loading this files in a loop using absolutely the same connection string (except the filename), and the same functions.

Thank you in advance,
J.

Comment: You need to change the connection string for the Worksheet that has no header to `HDR=No` HDR is an abbreviation for Header!

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the solution. Now, both files have no header. I want to have the columns of the datatable be named by the header of the excel sheet.

Comment: The correct way to mark your question as being resolved to your satisfaction is to *accept* an answer. Not to change the title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I opened the file and saved it another time - not the import functioned. Maybe, this file had an old format - I received it via EM@il.